# Get text from <span> on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the like button div is clicked I am trying to get the content from its span. I know I need to use .text() but im having trouble selecting the corresponding span for each div.

```
$(".like").click(function(event){       
   event.stopPropagation();                     
   $("i", this).toggleClass("icon-thumbs-up-alt").toggleClass("icon icon-thumbs-up");  
   console.log($('.hideThis').text());
});
```

returns the string in each span. Do I need to use "this" somewhere?

```
<div class= "postInfo1>
 <span class="hideThis" style="display:"none">3453652545</span>
</div
<div class="like">Like Button</div>


<div class= "postInfo2>
 <span class="hideThis" style="display:"none">3453652545</span>
</div
<div class="like">Like Button</div>


<div class= "postInfo3">
 <span class="hideThis" style="display:"none">3453652545</span>
</div
<div class="like">Like Button</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot a `>` in `</div>` and `"` after the postInfo classes.

Comment: it also should be `style="display:none;"` vs `style="display:"none"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and try this:

```
$(".like").click(function(event){       
   event.stopPropagation();                     
   $("i", this).toggleClass("icon-thumbs-up-alt").toggleClass("icon icon-thumbs-up");  
   console.log($(this).prev('div').find('.hideThis').text()); //Find the previous div relative to the clicked span and insisde that find hideThis
});
```

And remember to close your div, qoutes after the classname `postInfo1` and remove quotes in the style value `style="display:"none"`;

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zDndv/)**

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to use "this" somewhere?

Yes, so you can traverse the DOM having `this` (the clicked element) as the starting point:

```
$('.like').click(function(event) {
    //...
    console.log( $(this).prev().find('.hideThis').text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way -

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/v4mew/

```
$(".like").click(function(event){       
   event.stopPropagation();     
   $("i", this).toggleClass("icon-thumbs-up-alt").toggleClass("icon icon-thumbs-up");                  
   console.log($(this).prev('div').find('.hideThis').text());
});
```

Corrected markup -

```
<div class="postInfo1"> <span class="hideThis" style="display:none">3453652545</span> 
</div>
<div class="like">Like Button</div>
<div class="postInfo2"> <span class="hideThis" style="display: none">3453652545</span> 
</div>
<div class="like ">Like Button</div>
<div class="postInfo3"> <span class="hideThis" style="display: none">3453652545</span>
</div>
<div class="like ">Like Button</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your markup is all jacked up.  You have strings and tags that aren't closed.

I cleaned it up for you

```
<div class="postInfo1"> <span class="hideThis" style="display:none">3453652545</span>

</div>
<div class="like">Like Button</div>
<div class="postInfo2"> <span class="hideThis" style="display:none">3453652545</span>

</div>
<div class="like">Like Button</div>
<div class="postInfo3"> <span class="hideThis" style="display:none">3453652545</span>

</div>
<div class="like">Like Button</div>
```